# Prefab disables its script when a clone is instantiated

Tags: unity, javascript

A clone of a cube is spawned when it is destroyed, however the clones disable the script in the editor (example: http://gfycat.com/SnarlingScornfulEgg). Used the exact same script for a different kind of 'enemy' and it worked as intended.

Relevant part of script:

```
function Start () {
    health = 100;
}

function Update () {
    if(health <= 0){
        Dead();
    }
}

function OnCollisionEnter (col : Collision) {
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet"){
        health-=25;
    }
}   

function Dead () {
    Destroy(gameObject);
    var posx = Random.Range(-50, 50);
    var posz = Random.Range(-50, 50);
    Instantiate(enemyl, Vector3(posx, 0.5, posz), transform.rotation);
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: The clone takes damage but doesn't die like the original when its health is <= 0.

Comment: Maybe the script is disabled on your prefab itself?

Comment: @Dimitrimx Checked, it isn't.

Comment: In that case [Instantiated Objects script not enabled](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/45079/instantiated-objects-scripts-not-enabled-not-sure.html) will most likely answer you question.

Comment: Looks like it's not properly being destroyed either, have you found the cause for that? It's likely related.

Comment: @Byte56 Not sure what you mean exactly. The cube is removed from the Hierarchy evident in the video. Is there something else I should be looking at?

Comment: I suppose you're correct. It's just that two clones replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your video it appears that the cloned `EnemyL` object has an `EnemyL(Clone)` as the value for the variable `enemyl`.

I suggest ensuring that the `EnemyL` prefab has the `EnemyL` prefab as the value for its variable `enemyl`.

---

Thanks for posting image below.  It appears that you have the prefab "linked to itself" and when cloned at runtime these clones are also "linked to themselves".  As such any changes to state will propagate from one generation to the next.

In your case when you call `Destroy(gameObject)` and then `Instantiate(enemyl, ...)` both are referring to the same object.  As you are cloning a partially destroyed GameObject the resulting clone has unexpected behavior.

Here is a [discussion](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/reference-to-prefab-changing-to-clone-self-reference.57312/) of this (self referential prefab)  issue on the Unity forums.  There are a couple of solutions and workarounds discussed.

Two of these options are:

1. Move the prefab into the resources folder, change the variable declaration and Awake() to something like this:

   ```
   private var enemyl : Transform =  null;

   function Awake() {
       if(enemyl == null) {
           enemyl = Resources.Load("EnemyL");
       }
   }
   ```

   This will create a link from the object in the scene to the prefab in the project.  Now that it is not a self referential link, state will not propagate to later generations.
2. Alternatively the cloning functionality can be moved to a separate, stable, helper object and called upon when required.

Comment: Since the prefab object is named `EnemyL (Clone)`, it seems correct to have that as its value.

Comment: The `Assets\Prefabs` directory has an item called `EnemyL` and the video starts with an object called `EnemyL` in the hierarchy.  Its hard to say whats going on without seeing the inspector for either the scene objects or the prefabs, but having a clone as the variable to be cloned *may* be a mistake.  If `Instantiate()` is producing objects of an unexpected state then checking the state of whatever is being cloned would be a good next step.

Comment: @KellyThomas The EnemyL variable has the original EnemyL prefab assigned, not the clone. http://i.imgur.com/e8E33Ur.png